# Round up a Double to a whole number in the request parameter value in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to be able to round the `Load` in the below piece of code in the request parameter value in Spring MVC, fairly new to the field, so not sure if the `round(Load)` will work as it does in core java. It's a double field that may contain decimals like 4.2345, and I simply want to retrieve it as 4.

How i can do that?

```
@RequestParam(value = "Load", required = false)
```

Comment: Once it is stored into a variable by Spring, what you do with it is just as usual in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Then convert it inside your method.

For example:

```
public void method(@RequestParam("Load") double load){
    int intValue = (int)load;
    '''
}
```